# How do I play the "Homeworld Remastered Original Soundtracks"?

Tags: steam, homeworld-remastered-collection

Gearbox recently released the original Homeworld soundtracks via Steam, and also provided DLC codes for Collector's Edition owners to download them for free. Having purchased the Collector's Edition, I've already received my DLC code and activated it in Steam. This appears to have prompted an update to the Homeworld Remastered game, but I can't see anything in Steam that appears to allow me to access the music.

I went to Library->Music, but it says "We've come up empty!". I tried checking in-game menus, but didn't see anything. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

Two things I've figured out:

1. The music files are downloaded to the following path by default. They're in MP3 and FLAC format. You should be able to play them in your media player of preference from here. (MP3s played fine in Windows Media Player, and FLAC played in VLC, for me.)

   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Homeworld\Soundtrack`
2. You may need to configure the Steam music library to scan for the content. You can specify the appropriate path to be scanned, or tell it to "Scan Steam folders for soundtracks" - either should work. Finish reading the aforementioned error and you'll see a link titled "in settings" - this will take you where you need to go. You may need to force a re-scan to see the music or, if it's configured to "Scan at startup", just restart Steam. Afterwards, the soundtracks should be available in Library->Music.

Note: For option two, you must have at least one folder configured in your Music Library for Steam to detect anything using the "Scan Steam folders for soundtracks" option. It doesn't matter what that folder is, or if it even contains any music, but Steam won't include anything in the scan if there are no explicitly defined folders.

(Screenshots coming later.)